# Query for deleting entries while ignoring the last X entries?

Tags: sqlite, sql-delete

I'm trying to figure out a query to delete rows from a database where we leave a certain number.

For example, if we have 10 entries and want to delete all but 2, how would I do this?

I was thinking I could count the number of entries in the table, then run a delete query using a limit of (Max Size - X), but I feel like there should be a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find a query for the rows you want to keep, then exclude them from the deletion:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID
                 FROM MyTable
                 ORDER BY Whatever
                 LIMIT 2)
```